# Is there a option in Activecollab to link a git repository commit to a task comment?

Tags: git, repository, activecollab

I added a git repository to my activeCollab project. The commits are shown properly with their messages under the "sources"- tab.
My question is now: Is there ANY way to link my repo commits with the comments under the task they are linked to? I know that in default there is no way. I am more interested in a work around that actually makes that possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "mention" a task in commit message by using `#TaskID` (or `#TaskId@ProjectSlug` if one Git repository is connected to more than one project). More info about this can be found in Active Collab documentation:

https://help-classic.activecollab.com/books/source/commit-messages-and-tasks.html

Note that there is no way to add a commit as a comment to task, but all commits that are related to a task can be found in Commits dialog that you can access from Options drop-down.

Comment: ok that is what I wanted to know... wanted to be sure if there really is no way...

Comment: To link tasks and commits, yes, to have commits as comments, no. Sorry :(